# Three ways to say "I danced for three hours".

Tags: grammar, difference

Based on the other examples of our book, I can imagine three ways to say this:

> 我跳舞跳了三個小時。
>
> 我跳了三個小時的舞。
>
> 我跳了三個小時的跳舞。

Are they all correct and do they have exactly the same meaning?

Comment: grammar topic: 数量补语｜二、时量补语２，宾语的位置 search site for previous discussions, note 跳舞 is of type V+O (in fact a 离合词，＂separable word＂）

Comment: this is what ＂实用现代汉语语法＂says about the difference between 1 and 2: 如果动作涉及的事物第一次出现，不说宾语意思不清楚时（evidently applying to 跳舞），通常要重复谓语动词，宾语位于第一动词后，补语位于第二动词后。例如：（１）我们坐车坐了四十多分钟。（２）老李听报告听了一下午。（３）刚才我找小刘找了半天。（４）我喊你喊了有十分钟了。如果宾语在上文已出现，或在一定的语境中不说出来所指也清楚时，可以不重复谓语动词，这时宾语有以下几种位置：（１）当宾语是表示一般事物或抽象事物的名词时，一般位于时量补语后，补语与宾语之间还可以用＂的＂，有表示时间长的意思。例如：（１）我今天写了二十分钟（的）汉字。（２）为了这件事，我们开了两个晚上（的）会。（３）我们今天上了将近百天（的）课。（４）小明打了一下午的球。（５）昨天我们看了一天的电影。i.p. 2 can be shortened to 我跳了三个小时舞。（２）宾语表示确定的人的名词、代词时，一般位于时量补语前。例如：（１）＂是啊，我替小刘一天。＂（２）我跟师傅这么多年，学到了不少东西。（３）小马等了你一个小时。（４）你观察老师这么多年，有什么发现？宾语为确定的人的名词，补语为＂一会儿＂、＂半天＂等不定时量时，可以在补语前，也可以在补语后。

Comment: 例如：（１）你等小刘一会儿吧。你等一会儿小刘吧。（２）我叫了半天李英她也不答应。我叫了李英半天她也不答应。（３）我陪一会儿老师。我陪老师一会儿。

Comment: @user6065 Do I understand correctly: we encourage repeating the PREDICATE when the OBJECT is newly introduced into the discussion? It is unclear to me, what part of speech "动作涉及的事物" usually is. I supposed the object?

Comment: exactly，
bkrs: 涉及  
involve; touch upon,
  relate to; 动作涉及的事物  "thing involved in the action", i.e. object of verb (comment started with @Ludi which repeatedly got erased)

Comment: @user6065 thank you very much. I think when a user is automatically notified, because, for instance he is the author of a post, then the at-reference gets deleted. I think it holds on all stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st one and 2nd one are both correct, and have almost same meaning; but different emphasis.

The emphasis of the 1st one is the lasting time, i.e. `三個小時`. e.g.

```
Q: 你跳舞跳了多长时间？ => The question is focused on how long
A: 我跳舞跳了三个小时。
```

The emphasis of the 2nd one is what (sb. do). e.g.

```
Q: 你下午做什么去了？ => The question is focused on what you did
A: 我跳了三个小时的舞。
```

The 3rd one is wrong. At the end of the sentence a noun is expected; which should be the object of the preceding verb, i.e. `跳`.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. 我跳舞跳了三個小時。

It is a [topic]+[comment/opinion] structure.

[我跳舞](I dance) is the topic.

[跳了三個小時] is the comment that provides more details on the topic.

> 2. 我跳了三個小時的舞。

It is a [subject]+ [verb] + [object] structure.

[我] (I) is the subject.

[跳了] (danced) is the verb.

[舞] (dance) is the object.

[三個小時的] (three hours of) is the relative clause for the object that makes [三個小時的舞] as a whole, the object.

**Both sentences above are grammatically correct and have the same meaning.**

> 3.我跳了三個小時的跳舞。

This one is grammatically incorrect. The second 跳 is not needed. You don't need two identical verbs for the same object.